# yadcf interface change to exFilterColumn confusion

Tags: yadcf

I am upgrading the yadcf version on my site from 0.6.9 to 0.8.8. (I'm also upgrading from datatables 1.9.4 to 1.10.10)

See the 0.6.9 version at [my production site](http://steeplechasers.org/scoretility/viewstandings/?club=fsrc&series=grandprix&desc=Frederick%20Steeplechasers%20Running%20Club%20-%202015%20grandprix&year=2015) and the 0.8.8 version at [my sandbox site](http://sandbox.steeplechasers.org/scoretility/viewstandings/?club=fsrc&series=grandprix&desc=Frederick%20Steeplechasers%20Running%20Club%20-%202015%20grandprix&year=2015)

I have updated my calls to `yadcf.exFilterColumn` from two calls to a single call because now the defaults take an array of pairs.

But my filtered dataset is empty when the page loads, and I need to select a gender then click all for all the data to show up.

I'm sure it's something I'm not quite getting for the new interface.

**Update:** Simplified sandbox version [here](http://sandbox.steeplechasers.org/scoretility/_teststandings/). See file TestStandings.js

**Update 2:** Daniel pointed out that "-1" for gender filter won't work. Apparently usegender = "-1" doesn't behave the same way in 0.8.8 as it did in 0.6.9 for some reason. I could try to figure out why it used to work, but that seems unproductive.

I added the following code after the exFilterColumn call (it's necessary for the gender to be filtered in some use cases)

```
    // reset gender column if didn't mean to filter
    if (usegender == "-1") {
        yadcf.exResetFilters( _rrwebapp_table, [genderCol] )
    }
```

but this gets exception at line 3624 of jquery.dataTable.yadcf.js because `settingsDt.aanFeatures.f` is undefined

**Update 3:** while debugging on the datatables side, I changed sDom from '<"H"Clpr>t' to the default 'lfrtip'. The exception mentioned above went away and the table loaded properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you should handle your scenario

Its wrong to ask for filtering for a `-1` value because there is no such value in the table, so in order to reset a specific column just before calling `exFilterColumn` you should use the [exResetFilters with noRedraw set to true](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/1201bacc94689d76ec13a0dbbc24272b707a1955/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L289) (grab from *0.8.9.beta.31*) you should call this function **before** your `exFilterColumn`

---

**Old answer**

I might have noticed multiple calls to the `exFilterColumn` for the same table, while in fact you should call it only once, just set the desired values for each column of the table,

[See showcase page (first table)](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/multiple_tables.html)

And notice the relevant code below

```
yadcf.exFilterColumn(firstTable, [
    [1, {
        from: 1,
        to: 40
    }],
    [3, "a_value"]
]);
```

If it still no goodm please provide the your table / yadcf init code and the code for calling the `exFilterColumn`

---

Update:

I noticed that your are using the following line of code

`yadcf.exFilterColumn(_rrwebapp_table, [[divisionCol, usedivision], [genderCol, usegender]])`

Where your `usegender` is set to `"-1"` which makes no sense, because its the value of the *Select input reset option*, so make sure you dont use `"-1"` as values in your `exFilterColumn` calls...

Comment: There was a second call, sorry about the confusing cut/paste error. Removing the second call had no effect.

I simplified the code at http://sandbox.steeplechasers.org/scoretility/_teststandings/ . Please see the function viewstandings inside TestStandings.js

Comment: Regarding "-1", this is probably the reason for the different behavior between 0.6.9 and 0.8.8 (you can see this in the production version, but would have to dig through the larger code set). I was using "-1" to reset the gender filter initially in 0.6.9. What is the value I need to use to have that filter cleared in 0.8.8?

Comment: I've added a call to exResetFilters after the exFilterColumn call, but this gets exception. Please see updated question.

Comment: the "updated question" above refers to Update 2. In Update 3 I replaced sDom parameter with default. Exception went away and table loaded. So I'll mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I found exception was fixed in a 0.8.9.beta.10 based on https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/220. Just wondering if you have a target date for 0.8.9 ?

Comment: No plans for a specific date, but it should happen in the following week or two