# datatables width behavior change between 1.9.4 and 1.10.10

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am upgrading the datables version on my site from 1.9.4 to 1.10.10. (I'm also upgrading from yadcf 0.6.9 to 0.8.8)

See the 1.9.4 version at [my production site](http://steeplechasers.org/scoretility/viewstandings/?club=fsrc&series=grandprix&desc=Frederick%20Steeplechasers%20Running%20Club%20-%202015%20grandprix&year=2015) and the 1.10.10 version at [my sandbox site](http://sandbox.steeplechasers.org/scoretility/viewstandings/?club=fsrc&series=grandprix&desc=Frederick%20Steeplechasers%20Running%20Club%20-%202015%20grandprix&year=2015), with simpler version of sandbox use of datatables in viewstandings function within TestStandings.js [here](http://sandbox.steeplechasers.org/scoretility/_teststandings/)

Due to [yadcf interface change to exFilterColumn confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213024/yadcf-interface-change-to-exfiltercolumn-confusion), in the sandbox site you have to select a gender to see the problem I'm discussing now.

As you can see the table header and the table data widths are sized differently.

I see that the `div` with class `dataTables_scrollHeadInner` has a smaller width attribute value in the sandbox site than in the production site, where it looks nice and takes the whole width.

What I don't know is what is causing that. I'm guessing there is a new configuration parameter I need to set, or the way I had it set for 1.9.4 doesn't work well for 1.10.10.

Comment: How is this question related to yadcf? I mean it is tagged with yadcf but I dont see how yadcf can help to solve it

Comment: may not be, but I wasn't sure -- my mistake was I was looking at the next div first which had a yadcf class, but after I'd realized there was an outer div without that class I forgot to remove the tag, which has been removed now

Comment: Thanks to Gyrocode.com for the edits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was setting sScrollX: "100%". Not sure why this caused the behavior, and not sure why I'd set this when using 1.9.4.

I had a hunch after looking at the datatables code around where the width was being set (line 3753), and it panned out.